# Google Drive file: Item not found or you are not authorized to access it

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am very very new to Google API's :  I have gone thru documentation and my app [from android-demos-master] creates a file successfully and the content is "Hello World". The  When trying to retrieve contents, the app connects successfully and the DriveID is returned.  However, Status code 1502 "item not found or you do not have authorization" is retuned.

What am I doing wrong?

Manifest [ although the Activity Intent filter does not sem to fullfil any function]:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dishes4"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission 
     android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateFileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_file" >



    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BaseDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base_demo" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RetrieveContentsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_retrieve_contents" >

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=108614704480-ohna61c6boi21ak393pqhvjh1dm1or6f.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />

    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The RetrieveContentsActivity which causes the problem:

```
package com.example.dishes4;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveIdResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;


public class RetrieveContentsActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "RetrieveContentsActivity";
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_contents);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    tv.append("Connected");
    showMessage("Connected");
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
    tv.append("........   finising fetching DriveID");

}


final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        tv.append("Got a result!!!!!!!!!!!      ");
        showMessage("Got a result!!!!!!!!!!!      ");
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            tv.append("Success  DriveIDResult");

        tv.append(result.toString());
        DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
            return;
        }

        else
        {tv.append("Status code:  "+Integer.toString(result.getStatus().getStatusCode())+"     ");
        showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
        return;}
    }
};
}
```

The CreateFileActivity

```
  package com.example.dishes4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder.DriveFileResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class CreateFileActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private static final String TAG = "CreateFileActivity";

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient())
            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello World!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("New file")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file on root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
    }
};
}
```

and the BaseDemoActivity they both extend

```
package com.example.dishes4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;


public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";
public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";
protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";
protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

public void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
  return mGoogleApiClient;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi iam facing the same problem .It has been 2 days i don't get perfect doc for google drive api kindly send me an link or solution You used to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has answered your question. I take the liberty to answer, even if it is more than a few weeks old.

When you create your file you show your drive-id with the following lines:
    showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());

Then when reading your file you are using a constant:

```
Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
        .setResultCallback(idCallback);
```

Make sure that EXISTING_FILE_ID is the value you got when creating your file. Maybe it would be better to write result.getDriveFile().getDriveId() to the log, rather than showing it to the screen for a few seconds. 
Replace:

```
showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
```

with:

```
Log.d("DriveID",Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
```

Then make a note of the drive-id, and update the constant: EXISTING_FILE_ID.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer which looks very useful.  I will be getting back to this in due course and let you know how I got on